# python requests 403 for json, however in browsers works fine

Tags: python, api, python-requests, http-headers, user-agent

I'm trying to get data from etoro. This link works in my browser https://www.etoro.com/sapi/userstats/CopySim/Username/viveredidividend/OneYearAgo but it's forbidden via `request.get()` even if I add user agent, headers and even cookies.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.etoro.com/sapi/userstats/CopySim/Username/viveredidividend/OneYearAgo"
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.etoro.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.etoro.com/people/viveredidividend/chart',
    'Cookie': 'XXX',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> <Response [403]>
```

How to solve it without selenium?

Comment: It's HTTP/2. You can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019868/authority-http-header-in-chrome-dev-tools

Comment: ever figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

The error 403 tells that the request you are making is getting blocked. Actually, the website is protected by [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) which is preventing the website to get scraped. You can check it by executing `print(response.text)` in your code and you'll see `Access denied | www.etoro.com used Cloudflare to restrict access` in the returned cloudflare HTML inside title tag.

Under the hood, when you sent the requests it goes through the cloudflare server and verify whether it's coming from the real browser or not. If the request pass the verification then only it forward the request to website server which returns the valid response. Otherwise, the cloudflare block the request.

It's difficult to bypass cloudflare. Nevertheless, you can try your luck with the code given below.

**Code**

```
import urllib.request


url = 'https://www.etoro.com/sapi/userstats/CopySim/Username/viveredidividend/OneYearAgo'
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.etoro.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accounttype': 'Real',
    'applicationidentifier': 'ReToro',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'applicationversion': '331.0.2',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/cryptocurrencies',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': '__cfruid=e7f40231e2946a1a645f6fa0eb19af969527087e-1624781498; _gcl_au=1.1.279416294.1624782732; _gid=GA1.2.518227313.1624782732; _scid=64860a19-28e4-4e83-9f65-252b26c70796; _fbp=fb.1.1624782732733.795190273; __adal_ca=so%3Ddirect%26me%3Dnone%26ca%3Ddirect%26co%3D%28not%2520set%29%26ke%3D%28not%2520set%29; __adal_cw=1624782733150; _sctr=1|1624732200000; _gaexp=GAX1.2.eSuc0QBTRhKbpaD4vT_-oA.18880.x331; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjid=bb69919f-e61b-4a94-a03b-db7b1f4ec4e4; hp_preferences=%7B%22locale%22%3A%22en-gb%22%7D; funnelFromId=38; eToroLocale=en-gb; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; marketing_visitor_regulation_id=10; marketing_visitor_country=96; __cflb=0KaS4BfEHptJdJv5nwPFxhdSsqV6GxaSK8BuVNBmVkuj6hYxsLDisSwNTSmCwpbFxkL3LDuPyToV1fUsaeNLoSNtWLVGmBErMgEeYAyzW4uVUEoJHMzTirQMGVAqNKRnL; __cf_bm=6ef9d6f250ee71d99f439672839b52ac168f7c89-1624785170-1800-ASu4E7yXfb+ci0NsW8VuCgeJiCE72Jm9uD7KkGJdy1XyNwmPvvg388mcSP+hTCYUJvtdLyY2Vl/ekoQMAkXDATn0gyFR0LbMLl0b7sCd1Fz/Uwb3TlvfpswY1pv2NvCdqJBy5sYzSznxEsZkLznM+IGjMbvSzQffBIg6k3LDbNGPjWwv7jWq/EbDd++xriLziA==; _uetsid=2ba841e0d72211eb9b5cc3bdcf56041f; _uetvid=2babee20d72211eb97efddb582c3c625; _ga=GA1.2.1277719802.1624782732; _gat_UA-2056847-65=1; __adal_ses=*; __adal_id=47f4f887-c22b-4ce0-8298-37d6a0630bdd.1624782733.2.1624785174.1624782818.770dd6b7-1517-45c9-9554-fc8d210f1d7a; _gat=1; TS01047baf=01d53e5818a8d6dc983e2c3d0e6ada224b4742910600ba921ea33920c60ab80b88c8c57ec50101b4aeeb020479ccfac6c3c567431f; outbrain_cid_fetch=true; _ga_B0NS054E7V=GS1.1.1624785164.2.1.1624785189.35; TMIS2=9a74f8b353780f2fbe59d8dc1d9cd901437be0b823f8ee60d0ab36264e2503993c5e999eaf455068baf761d067e3a4cf92d9327aaa1db627113c6c3ae3b39cd5e8ea5ce755fb8858d673749c5c919fe250d6297ac50c5b7f738927b62732627c5171a8d3a86cdc883c43ce0e24df35f8fe9b6f60a5c9148f0a762e765c11d99d; mp_dbbd7bd9566da85f012f7ca5d8c6c944_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2217a4c99388faa1-0317c936b045a4-34647600-13c680-17a4c993890d70%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2217a4c99388faa1-0317c936b045a4-34647600-13c680-17a4c993890d70%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D',
}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
print(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error gives when you doesn't authenticate the python code in browser. When you login with website it is authenticate and its remember it, thats why you can use and works fine in browser by site.

In order to solve this problem you first need to authenticate the browser in your python code.

**To authenticate,**

```
 import requests

response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
```